# UIWebView Not Loading View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

My UIWebView doesn't seem to be loading:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewDidAppear:animated];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *urlAddress = [defaults stringForKey:@"webPage"];
NSLog(@"%@", urlAddress);

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]];
webView.delegate = self;
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

It is in a UIViewController (connected through IB) and urlAddress returns google.com

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the URL being fetched is valid?

```
    NSString *urlAddress = [defaults stringForKey:@"webPage"];
    NSLog(@"%@", urlAddress);
    NSURL *u = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    if(u){
      NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:u];
      webView.delegate = self;
      [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    }else{
      [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"invalid url." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
```

google.com is not a valid url, it should be http://www.google.com. So maybe that is the issue here.

Comment: It's valid with http:

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        webView.delegate = self;
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *urlAddress = [defaults stringForKey:@"webPage"];
        NSLog(@"%@", urlAddress);
        [self openURLFromString:urlAddress];
    }

    - (void) openURLFromString:(NSString*) urlString
    {
        NSURL *url = [self validateAddress:urlString];
        NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
    }

    - (NSURL*) validateAddress:(NSString*) address
    {
        NSURL* result = [NSURL URLWithString:address];
        if (!result.scheme)
        {
            NSString* modifiedURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", address];
            result = [NSURL URLWithString:modifiedURLString];
        }

        return result;
    }

    #pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)urlRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {
        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing **base URL** part of the URL ( [Click here to read more about this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ), which is necessary.

So try this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewDidAppear:animated];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *urlAddress = [defaults stringForKey:@"webPage"];
NSString * theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", urlAddress]; // you can also use stringByAppendingString if you prefer
NSLog(@"%@", theURL);

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL]];
webView.delegate = self;
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

HTH :)